# PHP How to add Values stored in Rows rather than Columns?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento

I need to add write a php script to run from a cron job that will add two Magento Attribute values and store the result as a third attribute in the MySQL database.

Any help would be appreciated.  I've attached a screen shot that hopefully clarifies things.

Comment: If you can provide an SQL example of what you're trying to do I will try and provide an answer.

Comment: I think there may be an error in your question. Your image says row with attribute 141 should have the value of the summation, but your textual description says that the row with attribute_id 145 should have it.

Comment: That's correct The line should be "Set the value from row attribute_id 141 entity_id W to Z" but I'm unable to edit my original post.  Apparently I don't have enough points to post an image.  Well I did but now I can't edit because of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working directly in SQL when dealing with EAV models is hard. Save yourself the effort and use Magento's classes instead. A minimal cron script might look something like this:

```
<?php

require 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product->setSumValue(
        $product->getFirstValue() + $product->getSecondValue()
    )
    ->save();
}
```

Magento provides magic methods so you can use syntax like `getFirstValue()`, `getSecondValue()` and `setSumValue()` to refer to attributes named `first_value`, `second_value` and `sum_value` respectively. Use the names of your actual attributes instead of the numbers 141, etc.

Comment: If your intention is to keep the third value up to date then it would be wise to work with Magento's framework and create a listener for save events. It would update the attribute whenever the others are updated, negating the need for a cron and avoiding the short period when they are out of sync.

Comment: That's exactly my intention.  The value of "Attribute _id" 145 is set by a custom php script so I guess another option would be to add it to add it to the end of that script?  I'm also just a little confused by your explanation of the attribute names.  Am I correct that if the attributes are named 145 = "stock_in_hand", 146 = "stock_in_transit" and 141 = "tot_inventory" I would remove the underscores and use :-               


settotinventory(
        $product->getstockinhand() + $product->getstockintransit()

Comment: Or is it setTotInventory( $product->getStockInHand() + $product->getstockInTransit()

Comment: BTW I just realised you're the REAL Clockwork Geek Magento Extension Developer!!  I'm honored!!  :)

Comment: It's [camel case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) so "tot_inventory" becomes `setTotInventory`. You were right second time. If "stock_in_hand" is being set in another script then that is the ideal time to update "tot_inventory" too.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it, but I haven't tested it.

The basic procedure is to create a temporary table which contains the summed values for those entities you care about, then update the proper attribute rows with those values.

Note that php is not necessary here, only SQL. You may of course want to use php to issue the query.

```sql
UPDATE 
catalog_product_entity_decimal, 
(SELECT entity_id, SUM(value) AS summedvalue FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal as cped 
    WHERE attribute_id IN (145, 146)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal WHERE entity_id=cped.entity_id and attribute_id=141)
    GROUP BY entity_id 
) AS sums

SET catalog_product_entity_decimal.value = sums.summedvalue
WHERE catalog_product_entity_decimal.entity_id=sums.entity_id
    AND catalog_product_entity_decimal.attribute_id=141;
```

This builds an intermediate table `sums` that looks like this (based on data in table screenshot):

```
entity_id | summedvalue
1         | 12
2         | 0
```

If there's an entity_id without a row with an attribute_id=141, that entity_id won't have a row in this `sums` table--this is ensured by the EXISTS() condition.

Then we update the `catalog_product_entity_decimal` table (I'll abbreviate it CPED) by joining it with `sums` on the entity_id.

```
CPED.entity_id | CPED.attribute_id | sums.entity_id | sums.summedvalue
1              | 145               | 1              | 12
2              | 145               | 2              | 0
```

`SET CPED.value = sums.summedvalue` does the actual setting.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for that!!  I think I'm understanding.  But can you clarify "AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal WHERE entity_id=cped.entity_id and attribute_id=141)"  If I;m understanding this correctly then it will only update product 1 and not move on to product 2 etc.

Comment: This requires that entity_id the in `sums` pseudo-table have a row somewhere in `catalog_product_entity_decimal` table with an attribute_id=141.  It's a filter.  You could accomplish the same thing with a self inner join using that condition. (In fact there are few different SQL solutions.)

Comment: Is it clearer if I explain the required function like this 

FIND row ("attribute_id" = 141) SET ("temp_entity_id" = "entity_id")  

Find row ("attribute_id" = 145 AND "entity_id" = "temp_entity_id") SET ("stock_qty" = "Value")

Find row ("attribute_id" = 146 AND "entity_id" = "temp_entity_id") SET ("backorder_qty" = "Value")

SET ("offered_qty" = SUM ("stock_qty"+"backorder_qty"))

Find row (("attribute_id" = 141) AND ("entity_id" = "temp_entity_id")) SET ("value" = "qty_offered")

Clear ("temp_entity_id","stock_qty","backorder_qty","offered_qty")

GOTO Next "attribute_id" = 141

Comment: That's essentially what this sql does. You're thinking too procedurally. I'll expand my answer to explain more thoroughly.

Comment: Awesome!!  Thanks a bunch!!  I'm getting the following error when I try to run it though.  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE attribute_id IN (145, 146) AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM catalog_product_e' at line 4  I've had a look through the documentation on the error and nothing is standing out.  Any Ideas?

Comment: `GROUP BY` clause should be after `WHERE`.  But see @clockworkgeek answer, which is a much better approach. And please remove the ambiguity in your question about where the summed value goes.